# React: Why is the DIV that I wrap my JSX in suddenly very narrow and not allowing my layout to expand?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I had a site that was running for a year or so without any issues. It is an affiliate site and I was not making any money so I turned it off. I started it back up today and the entire layout is compressed into a single column. I found the issue, the elements are wrapped in a Div with a width set by the browser. If I modify the HTML in the browser and remove the div everything looks as it is supposed to.

When I go to my code, it turns out the div is the div I have to wrap my JSX code in. I can't remove it. Does anyone know how to resolve this? The website is http://www.thequickreviews.com/ (the site is on free hosting and may take 15 seconds to load) and if you look in dev tools for "this-div-is-narrow" you can see the div responsible.

The code in is:

```
render() {
        const sortedArray = categoryArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            var textA = a.categoryName.toUpperCase();
            var textB = b.categoryName.toUpperCase();
            return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
        });
        const productsListed = sortedArray.map(category => {
            return (
                    <Col xs={12} sm={4} md={4} lg={3} key={category.id}>
                        <Link onClick={this.goToTop.bind(this)} to={category.link}>
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <div className="full-width">
                                <Image className="images" onError={this.displayError.bind(this)} responsive src={category.image} alt={category.altTag} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="winners">
                                    <div className="placement">
                                        <div className="inner-container">
                                            <div className="category-text">{category.categoryName}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    </Col>
            )
        });
        return (
            <div class="this-div-is-narrow">
                <MetaTags>
                    <title>The Quick Reviews</title>
                    <meta id="meta-description" name="description" content="We make your buying decisions quick and easy by displaying and rating popular products in each category" />
                </MetaTags>
                {productsListed}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add `row` class to `this-div-is-narrow`

Like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <MetaTags>
        <title>The Quick Reviews</title>
        <meta id="meta-description" name="description" content="We make your buying decisions quick and easy by displaying and rating popular products in each category" />
    </MetaTags>
    {productsListed}
</div>
```